# exports is not defined webpack 4

Tags: webpack

I am using webpack 4 to bundle application resources.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "types":  ["node"], 
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "exclude": [
       "node_modules"    
    ]
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = require("./config/webpack.dev.js");
```

webpack.common.js:

```
//common webpack configuration
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var HtmlWebpackHarddiskPlugin = require('html-webpack-harddisk-plugin');
var helpers = require("./helpers.js");

module.exports = {
//the entry-point files that define the bundles
entry: {
    "polyfills": "./scripts/polyfills.ts",
    "vendor": "./scripts/vendor.ts",
    "main": "./scripts/main.ts"
},
//resolve file names when they lack extensions
resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".js"]
},
target: "node",
//decide how files are loaded
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loaders: [
                {
                    loader: "awesome-typescript-loader",
                    options: {
                        configFileName: helpers.root("./scripts", "tsconfig.json")
                    }                        
                }, "angular2-template-loader"
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: "html-loader"
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
            loader: "file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]"
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            exclude: helpers.root("./scripts", "app"),
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: "style-loader", use: "css-loader?sourceMap" })
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            include: helpers.root("./scripts", "app"),
            loader: "raw-loader"
        }
    ]
},
plugins: [
    // Workaround for angular/angular#11580
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
        // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
        /\@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)esm5/,
        helpers.root("./scripts"), // location of your src
        {} // a map of your routes
    ),
    //replaced by optimization.splitChunks for webpack 4
  //        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  //            name: ["app", "vendor", "polyfills"]
  //        }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: "./Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml",
        filename: "index.cshtml",
        alwaysWriteToDisk: true
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackHarddiskPlugin({            
    })
],
optimization: {
    splitChunks : {
        chunks: "async",
        minSize: 30000,
        minChunks: 1,
        maxAsyncRequests: 5,
        maxInitialRequests: 3,
        automaticNameDelimiter: '~',
        name: true,
        cacheGroups: {
            vendors: {
                test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                priority: -10
            },
            default: {
                minChunks: 2,
                priority: -20,
                reuseExistingChunk: true
            }
        }
    }
   }
  }
```

webpack.dev.js:

```
//development webpack configuration
var webpackMerge = require("webpack-merge");
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var commonConfig = require("./webpack.common.js");
var helpers = require("./helpers.js");

   module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
devtool: "cheap-module-eval-source-map",

output: {
    path: helpers.root("Views"),
    publicPath: "scripts/",
    filename: "[name].js",
    chunkFilename: "[id].chunk.js"
},

plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].css")
],

devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    stats: "minimal"
}
});
```

I am using angular5 and i have followed the official quickstart guide to build webpack configuration. Webpack is compiled successfully using 'npm start' command (development configuration) and the index.cshtml injects all 3 files i want:
1. polyfills.js
2. vendor.js 
3. main.js

The problem is that i get the following errors when these files are loaded from the browser:

```
polyfills.ts:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
at polyfills.ts:2
(anonymous) @ polyfills.ts:2
vendor.ts:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
at vendor.ts:1
(anonymous) @ vendor.ts:1
main.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
at main.js:2
(anonymous) @ main.js:2
```

Can anyone help me what is going wrong with the cofiguration?

Answer (score 7):

Add this to babel config plugins will solved this problem:

```
["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"]
```

Comment: this plugin tansforms ECMAScript modules to CommonJS. OP needs the opposite

Answer (score 6):

I had what appeared to be a very similar error in my Webpack 4 setup (with Babel 7). Webpack was building the bundle properly but when I was trying to load the file I was getting:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
at eval (util.js:22)
```

… where `util.js` was one of my own libraries.
I googled a lot of solutions that suggested configuring the `babel-loader` with `modules: false` and / or `sourceType: unambiguous` and/or setting `libraryTarget` (in the `output`) to 'umd') so I tried something like the following:

```
{test: /\.js$/, use:
     {
         loader: 'babel-loader',
         options:
         {
             presets: [
                 ['@babel/preset-env', {loose: true, modules: false}],
                 '@babel/react'
             ],
             sourceType: 'unambiguous'
         }
     }
}
```

… in the `rules` section of my `webpack.config.js`. No permutation of the above advises worked for me.
In the end, it was simply a matter of changing the following (from the end of my own `util.js` file), from:

```
exports.foo = foo;
exports.boo = boo;
```

… to:

```
export {foo, boo};
```

I append my (working) `webpack.config.js` and `package.json`

### webpack.config.js

```
'use strict';
const path = require('path');

const APPDIR = 'app/';

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: path.resolve(__dirname, APPDIR, 'index.html'),
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: 'body'
});

const config = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, APPDIR),
    entry: './main.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {test: /\.js$/, use:
             {
                 loader: 'babel-loader',
                 options:
                 {
                     presets: [
                         ['@babel/preset-env'], '@babel/react'
                     ]
                 }
             }
            },{
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    // style-loader
                    {loader: 'style-loader'},
                    // css-loader
                    {loader: 'css-loader',
                     options: {
                         modules: true
                     }
                    }]
            },{
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|woff)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: {
                            limit: 8192
                        }
                    }]
            },{
                test: /\.README$/,
                use: 'null-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig],

    node: {
        fs: "empty" // This is to account for what appears to be a bug: https://github.com/josephsavona/valuable/issues/9`
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

### package.json

```
{
"name": "cubehelix-demo",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -fr build/index.html && rm -fr build/bundle.js && npm run clean-logs",
    "build": "webpack --progress --colors",
    "build-min": "webpack --config=webpack.min.config.js",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --devtool eval --progress --colors --content-base build --port 8090",
    "test-build": "mkdir -p lib && babel app --out-dir lib --source-maps",
    "test": "npm run test-build && mocha --require source-map-support/register --compilers js:babel-register"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "~7.6.0",
    "@babel/core": "~7.6.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "~7.6.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/register": "~7.6.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "~7.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "chai": "~4.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "~3.2.0",
    "mocha": "~6.2.0",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "~4.39.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.8",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~3.8.0"
},
"dependencies": {
    "chai": "~4.2.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "jquery": "~3.4.1",
    "lodash": "~4.17.15",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-custom-validators": "*",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-timer-mixin": "~0.13.4"
}
}
```

Comment: A simple `export {foo, boo};` worked for me. Thanks for that simple solution

Comment: that fixed it finally! <3 don't ever use `export.bla = function() {}` always keep using `export {myfunction1, myfunction2}` to solve this

Comment: `sourceType: 'unambiguous'` got me to a solution and was all I needed. - the rationale is at https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4039#issuecomment-419284940 for webpack 5/babel 7

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution (it's what worked for me with an "exports is not defined" error): https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3974#issuecomment-369260590

> A solution for me anyway was change babel-loader config, under plugins, ['transform-runtime', { "polyfill": false }]

Comment: "This option was removed in v7 by just making it the default." - https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-runtime

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help anyone, as we have a very "special" setup where we hit this issue.

What we were seeing is that sym-linked shared libraries (via file:/ reference in package.json / npm link effectively) with dist directories were getting transpiled incorrectly by webpack.

We have the "symlinks: true" option specified in the "resolve" section in webpack and the resolution for us was to add to the `ignore` section in relevant `module.rules[]` section.

I believe this was because, even though the files were in `node_modules` with the symlinks present & followed, the resolved paths made it so the ignore pattern didn't find it and they got transpiled again (incorrectly)

```
diff --git a/project/webpack.config.js b/project/webpack.config.js
index f688472d72..a680c205e7 100644
--- a/project/webpack.config.js
+++ b/project/webpack.config.js
@@ -265,7 +265,10 @@ function webpackConfig(_target) {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
-            exclude: /node_modules/,
+            exclude: [
+              /node_modules/,
+              /node-lib/
+            ],
            use: {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
```

( our shared libraries show up in a sibling directory to `project` called `node-lib` )

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error. For me the problem was that I accidentally had a `main.js` besides my `main.ts`, causing webpack to use that one instead and for some reason not emit a lot of the imported modules. Deleting `main.js` solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

None of webpack config change above can fix it, only source code change can [fix: react-native-web with react-app-rewired and react-scripts@5 and webpack@5 cause `Uncaught Error: ES Modules may not assign module.exports or exports.*, Use ESM export syntax, instead: ./node_modules/@flyskywhy/react-native-gcanvas/index.js`](https://github.com/flyskywhy/react-native-gcanvas/commit/077dd6f321a1224d4ad7e07038258b0730bfb682), ref to https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4039#issuecomment-419284940

Comment: You don't necessarily have to change any code. You can use `babel` or other transpilers to do it for you.